# How to stop wordpress always displaying full-res images

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Currently, my website is over 56mb just on the home page... I have 5 images, it's far too large and is killing the speed.

Is there a way to make my site only display thumbnails or is this always theme dependent?

If it is theme dependent, I guess I will need to search inside the themes for where they display an image and edit?

Comment: Themes take care of most things themselves. However, Google "WordPress child theme". This will teach you how to make an edited version of a theme without actually editing the (parent) theme. You could then edit the front page template (if need be) or set smaller theme defaults for images.

Answer (score 0):

Well, images is one of WP's weak points.

First of all - stop uploading full sized images in first place, by that I mean photos from your camera, downloaded/self created artwork, high resolution, MB-heavy Photoshop creations etc..

My personal experience is that people mostly don't think about image size when uploading stuff to WordPress - but you have to - **before uploading**. Raw images from a camera, even a mobile phone can easily have 5-10 MB per image.

Unless your WordPress installation is expertly tuned to handle big images like a pro,
your WordPress installation will soon slow down and become huge.

Before you upload them, it is absolutely necessary to shrink images in size, with a tool (Photoshop, Gimp, etc.) (Sure, there are hundrets of plugins within the directory, some good, some bad).

To track down the issue, you can do several things:

- install "registered image sizes". This plugin will list all "registered images sizes" within WordPress and show you the available formats.
- go to "settings > media" and have a look at the default settings. You may want to shrink down the largest image size to maybe 1024 x 768 or something like that.
- after that, download and install "regenerate thumbnails". This plugin does a fairly good job of re-creating your thumbnails with an optimized size.
- You can also register your own image size within your functions.php and use that specific image size in your frontpage. See Codex: [Add Image Size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

Additional info: you can enter **"0" within "settings > media sizes"** (small, medium, large) in order to prevent WordPress from creating dozens of different image sizes.

As far as I know, the cropping option doesn't make any difference in this matter.

Also consider cleaning up your database with something like **wp optimize, or database cleaner**. WordPress saves every tiny little thing and bloats the database by default.

Lastly I'd recommend using a caching plugin in order to speed things up.
WordPress **Fastest Cache** is the tool of my choice in this matter.
It makes your loading process reallllly faster.

**Take-away**:

- only upload optimized images in first place
- optimize the image output (either by plugin or by yourself)
- use a caching plugin to speed things up